# Cron Job ebizmarts_ecommerce has an error: in magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-rule

I have uploaded  `ebizmarts_ecommerce` module in my live server.

> Cron Job ebizmarts_ecommerce has an error: : Argument 1 passed to  Magento\SalesRule\Model\Converter\ToDataModel::arrayToConditionDataModel() must be of the type array, string given, called in vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Converter/ToDataModel.php on line 110. 
>   Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":52690944,"emalloc_start":52091584} [] []
>   [2019-10-18 04:40:16] main.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0):  Error when running a cron job at also facing error on vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Converter/ToDataModel.php:216

anyone have an idea about this ?

Comment: contact ebizmarts support

Comment: Can you please let me know version of your MailChimp extension ?

Comment: MailChimp  extension version is : v102.3.37

Answer (score 0):

Please review these links.

https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/issues/528
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/mailchimp/mc-magento2/767/504145077

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I got issue in below path vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Converter/ToDataModel.php:216  for function arrayToConditionDataModel()...any idea about this error